# Derivative of a definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Calculate  $$ g'(x) $$ $$ g(x) =  \int_{0}^{2^x} \sin(t^2)dt  $$ for
>   $x = 0.$

I think that I could do it in similiar way as in this video: [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEN5rlK71IA)

but I don't know what to do because of $ \sin(t^2) $

Is this the solution?:
$$ \sin((2^x)^2) * 2^x\ln x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. You want $\log 2$. Do you see why?

In particular, let $\displaystyle h(x)=\int_0^x \sin t^2dt \;,\; f(x)=2^x$. Then $g=h\circ f$. And $f'=\cdots \;\;,\;\;(h\circ f)'=\cdots?$

Comment: ok, I see my mistake now :)  
So f' = 2^x * log2 and (h(f))' = sin((2^x)^2) * 2^x * log2 ?

Comment: @Badziubel Yes.